# Is there a term used for a new kanji that replaces an outdated one?

Tags: kanji, dictionary, writing-identification

Is there a term used for a new kanji that replaces an outdated one? 國 and 国 are good examples.

Comment: I assume the answer I provided is sufficient, as you *didn't provide one of these numerous examples*.

Comment: It'd be nice if you mentioned a few examples of the kanji you're inquiring about -- it'd make sure everyone is talking about the same thing.

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/42954/9831

Comment: 國 and 国 are good examples, since the new term is written differently from the old one. What is this called in Japanese?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

旧字体 Old-form　
新字体 New-form

Source: Just look up 國 or somesuch on Wiktionary.

Comment: What would the new kanji term be called?

Comment: Wha? You're confusing me, dude. Why don't you list some examples, like the comments under your post are asking?

Comment: 国 is a good example, as it is completely rewritten from its original form as provided in your original answer.

Comment: ? I'm confused. BJCUAI wrote `新字体 New-form`, so 新字体 is the term you're looking for, no? @Jack  

Comment: @Chocolate Yes it is.